# Upper and lower density of the set of natural numbers whose sum of positive divisors is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Let $A:=\{n \in \mathbb N : \sigma(n) \text{ is a perfect square}\}$ . I can show that $A$ is infinite . Let $A(n):=|A \cap [1,n]|$ . What can we say about $\liminf A(n)/n$ and $\limsup A(n)/n$ ?

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A006532](https://oeis.org/A006532) and references there.

Comment: Up to one million $1, 81, 400, 32\,400$ are elements of your set $A$ which are squares themselves

Comment: @RobertIsrael They say that the infinity of the set is a conjecture while the OP states that he/she can prove it...

Comment: $\text{lim sup } A(n)/n=1$  and $\text{lim inf } A(n)/n=0$

Comment: [Beukers, Luca and Oort](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.119.05.373) have a proof that the sequence is infinite.

Comment: @Raffaele : how do you determine the lim sup and lim inf ?

Comment: Experimentally, for the lim inf. The lim sup is quite obviously 1

Comment: @Raffaele : why is the lim sup "quite obviously " $1$ ? Do you have a proof or is this also experimental ...

Comment: for any $x\in A(n)$ we have $x\leq n$, equality is valid when $x\inA(n)$  so the ratio $A(n)/n leq 1$. For the liminf as $A(n)$ contains infinite elements the ratio behaves like $1/n\to 0$  as $n\to \infty$. This is not a proof, it is just a comment...